# NHibernate: Always evict entity after insertion

Tags: nhibernate

After inserting a particular type of entity I want to make sure that it is always evicted from the Session.

It seems I can do this with IPostInsertEventListener, but I'm not sure if it is safe.

Will this work:

```
public class LogUpdatesPostInsertEventListener : IPostInsertEventListener
{
    public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent insertEvent)
    {
        var entity = insertEvent.Entity;

        if (entity is Foo)
        {
            insertEvent.Session.Evict(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that??

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon - that is logging to database. Application can generate tons of such 'write-only' records. That's why they shouldn't be stored in session. In general, looks like nhibernate is not the best tool for it, but probably there is a way to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think given what you want to achieve the code that you have looks correct. I am wondering if you should add an explicit `Session.Flush()` to make sure that the insert is committed  to the database, but it depends on your requirement.

Also, make sure that you are working with only one session during one single unit of work for example for one HTTP request.